# How to only register Transform in debug buildtype

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I wrote a custom gradle plugin for android app, and I register a transform, but i just want to register it when current buildtype is debug. How can i achieve it.

```
public class CustomPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
     void apply(Project project) {
         project.android.registerTransform(new CustomTranform());
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get variant name from the context in which the transform is run: [javadoc](http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/javadoc/current/com/android/build/api/transform/Context.html#getVariantName--)

Which means you can write your transform this way:

```
class CustomTranform extends Transform {

    @Override
    public void transform(TransformInvocation invocation) {
        String variantName = invocation.getContext().getVariantName();
        if (variantName.toLowerCase().endsWith("debug")) {
            // actual transform
        } else {
            // no-op transform
        }
    }

    ...
}
```